# Animate images in uiimageview

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiimageview

How to animate the images from web service. I got the code to animate the images from bundle.How to load the images from the url  an array

That code is attached below

```
UIImageView* animatedImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
animatedImageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:    
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.gif"],
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.gif"],
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"image3.gif"],
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"image4.gif"], nil];
animatedImageView.animationDuration = 1.0f;
animatedImageView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
[animatedImageView startAnimating];
[self.view addSubview: animatedImageView];
```

Comment: Download the images, create an array and set `animationImages`, what is the problem here ?

Comment: any problem? seems the code is good

Comment: And the problem is...

Comment: Misleading and bad tagging, wrong title - flagged.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To download images from web service:

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:"*Url from web service*"];
UIImage *imageOne = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

likely download all images from web service and create an array like:

```
NSArray *imagesArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:imageOne...........,nil];
```

and use with little modification:

```
UIImageView* animatedImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
animatedImageView.animationImages = imagesArray;
animatedImageView.animationDuration = 1.0f;
animatedImageView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
[animatedImageView startAnimating];
[self.view addSubview: animatedImageView];
```

Comment: Just a side note: Make sure the downloading is not performed on the main thread.

Comment: no issues. But time takes for download . you have to wait patiently   till images get downloaded

Comment: Is it possible to change the background image of the uibutton in similar way

Comment: please ask your question clearly , you want to change after a button click or directly

Comment: Just an FYI, but your code will crash the device if the images are too large using this approach. Holding all decoded image data is memory is not a good idea, do some more research to find out how to fix that.

Comment: Crashes for me too.  Needs a better solution

Answer (score 2):

**Got a Perfect code for animation**
**can automatically change images in image view in swift4**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var imgarray = [UIImage(named:"f1.png")!, 
                UIImage(named:"f2.png")!, 
                UIImage(named:"f3.png")!,  
                UIImage(named:"f4.png")!,
                UIImage(named:"f5.png")!, 
                UIImage(named:"index1.png")!,
                UIImage(named:"index2.png")!, 
                UIImage(named:"index3.png")!]

@IBOutlet weak var imgview: UIImageView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.imgview.animationImages = imgarray
    self.imgview.animationDuration = 10.0
    self.imgview.animationRepeatCount = 0
    self.imgview.startAnimating()
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing its the answer To change images in a imageview automatically in a viewcontrol.

Answer (score 1):

### Swift

**Assuming that imageView is added via storyboard**

#### Intialize array:

```
self.imageArray = [UIImage(named:"Download_060.png")!,UIImage(named:"Download_061.png")!,UIImage(named:"Download_062.png")!,
                       UIImage(named:"Download_063.png")!,UIImage(named:"Download_064.png")!,UIImage(named:"Download_065.png")!,
                       UIImage(named:"Download_066.png")!,UIImage(named:"Download_067.png")!]
```

#### Add Code to animate on button action or as per required

```
 self.imgView.animationImages = self.imageArray
        self.imgView.animationDuration = 1.0
        self.imgView.animationRepeatCount = 0
        self.imgView.startAnimating()
```

#### Stop Animation

```
self.imgView.animationRepeatCount = 1 // IF Require once set this 1, 0 == infinite
```

**OR**

```
self.imgView.stopAnimating()
```