# SDWebImage animate images

Tags: ios, animation, uiimageview, nsarray, sdwebimage

I tried over 100 methods to animate images using SDWebImage but always fail. Do I understand good to using blocks? I am having IBOutlet property image names images1. I made array to store values and animate 3 images.

```
  NSMutableArray *imagegallery = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        NSLog(@"IMAGES-%@", imagegallery);


            [self.images1 setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.objc objectForKey:@"Img1"]]
                         placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]
                                completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {

                                    [imagegallery addObject:image];
                                    NSLog(@"Ima1-------%@", image);
                                }];
            [self.images1 setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.objc objectForKey:@"Img2"]]
                         placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]
                                completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {
                                    [imagegallery addObject:image];
                                }];
            [self.images1 setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.objc objectForKey:@"Img3"]]
                         placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]
                                completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {
                                    [imagegallery addObject:image];
                                }];

        self.images1.animationImages = imagegallery; //this line gets error
        self.images1.animationDuration = 0.5;
        [self.view addSubview:self.images1];
        [self.images1 startAnimating];
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: -[__NSCFConstantString _isResizable]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2fce30(lldb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think when you set `self.images1.animationImages = imagegallery` because your image couldn't be loaded yet, `method setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:completed:` is an asynchronous function. you should try another way
like: 
[Animate images in uiimageview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17274201/animate-images-in-uiimageview)

Comment: Yeah, it works,thanks. Anyway it take me about 2-3 secs to move to the ViewController with images without asynchronous function. Have you ever use this method before?

Comment: I thinks shouldn't use imageUrl to animationImages,instead, you can load one gif image url and set to your imageView. https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/blob/master/SDWebImage/UIImage%2BGIF.h

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that imageGallery contains strings as well as the images you add in the completed block. There's no reason to set imageGallery to be a copy of animatee in the first place since you never use those strings in imageGallery. Just create a new empty mutable array for imageGallery.

Comment: Anyway if I did it with empty mutable array(like edit question), it shows me no images. If I add more SdWebImage into NSMutableArray is it ok to use for all of them my IBOutlet property named images1?

Comment: @Milan1111, I don't think using setImageWithURL is really the right method to use to download a series of images, since it is setting the image of an image view -- by calling that 3 times in a row, you're changing the image three times which doesn't really make sense. I think you get no images because the download methods are asynchronous, and the line, self.images1.animationImages = image gallery, is running before the images come back. I haven't used SDWebImage, so I don't know what a more appropriate method to use would be.

Comment: Anyway, Thank you for help, how to think about it.