# images do not animate

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimageview

I want to slide images one by one automatically i am getting images from server with images path but it only show one image always what should i do?

```
for (SliderDC *slider in imagesArray) {
        sliderImageName = slider.sliderImagePath;
           NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",kWSURL, sliderImageName]]];
           UIImage *imgOne = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    ////        likely download all images from web service and create an array like
    //
          NSArray *imagesArrays = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:imgOne, nil];

////        and use with little modification
    //
        UIImageView* animatedImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
        animatedImageView.animationImages = imagesArrays;
        animatedImageView.animationDuration = 0.5f;
        animatedImageView.animationRepeatCount = 0;

        [self.view addSubview: animatedImageView];
        [animatedImageView startAnimating];
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand. You have only one image (in `imagesArays`). How is that supposed to be animated? Did you read how to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because your array contain only 1 image all time. your code should look like below.

```
NSMutableArray *imagesArrays= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (SliderDC *slider in imagesArray) {
    sliderImageName = slider.sliderImagePath;
       NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",kWSURL, sliderImageName]]];
       if(imageData)
           UIImage *imgOne = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
           if(imgOne)
               [imagesArrays addObject:imgOne];
}

// after adding all image in array then add animation.
UIImageView* animatedImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
animatedImageView.animationImages = imagesArrays;
animatedImageView.animationDuration = 0.5f;
animatedImageView.animationRepeatCount = 0;

[self.view addSubview: animatedImageView];
[animatedImageView startAnimating];
```

Comment: i am not giving same array plz check it is different name imagesArrays  not image array

Comment: i didn't downvote. and when you want to add animation you have to give array of all images which you want. right now `NSArray *imagesArrays = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:imgOne, nil];` this code only contain 1 image and you start animation. you have to pass array of images in ` animatedImageView.animationImages = imagesArrays;` this code.

Comment: i googled from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17274201/animate-images-in-uiimageview

Comment: @N.A it clearly says **likely download all images from web service and create an array like** and then apply that code . **and use with little modification**

Comment: yes i tried already but dont knw why it was not done.. but now working... :D