# Create realistic clouds in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, opengl-es, sprite-kit

I want to dynamically create realistic clouds including their movement and multiplication (density). I found this [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/70208/opengl-es-pixel-shaders-tutorial) which seem to explain more than I can understand. I cannot find a way to replicate the clouds and there is practically no other tutorial online. Does anyone know how can I achieve this result? Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: If you have a sequence of cloud images then you can animate them just like you had shown. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17274201/animate-images-in-uiimageview

Comment: I am not interested in adding moving images to my project thus its not what I'm looking for. Thank you though for your comment..

Comment: Theoretically you could create that with SpriteKit's `SKEmitterNode` but it would take some work...

Comment: @M321K i know, using the smoke profile. I tried but doesn't seem to resemble clouds thats why I searched for different ways..

Answer (score 1):

use **scene kit** you can make a dynamic particle effect:
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/SceneKitVehicle/Introduction/Intro.html

in this example you can find, after the vehicles code, the smoke animation. You can gat all the stuff you need from there, like smoke.scnp, smoke.png.

You need to change some row of code like the smoke color, the light color and the camera position.

But with that i guess you can have one of the best result possible, as real time cloud simulation, in iOS.

*(other solution would be using openGL but trust me this is a ton easier)*

*maybe this guide can also be useful to understand the basis (you just need them to achieve your clouds) :*
http://www.raywenderlich.com/83748/beginning-scene-kit-tutorial