# iOS CAKeyframeAnimation memory issue

Tags: ios, animation, memory

I have 100 png pictures and I'm using `CAKeyframeAnimation` to generate a layer which would play the animation.

The code is like this:

```
CAKeyframeAnimation *kfa = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"contents"];
kfa.values = animationImages; //CGImage type
kfa.removedOnCompletion = NO;
kfa.duration = 3.f;
kfa.repeatCount = CGFLOAT_MAX;
[layer addAnimation:kfa forKey:nil];
```

Each image is 1338*1338 pixel, so when rendering this animation, the memory is going sky high. (1338*1338*4B)

So how can I reduce the memory use and get acceptable performance?

Comment: Another option to the answer could be to use AVAssetWriter to create a movie but I would only go down this road if needed in an export.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would avoid key frame animations when doing this. A simple timer should be able to do your job but you could also look into native functionality of `UIImageView`. There is a property `animationImages`. Please take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17274478/526828). Though this one will also consume absurd amount of memory.

Anyway, if you choose to do this manually still make sure that you release your memory as soon as possible. You may still need some internal autorelease pools:

```
@autoreleasepool {
    // Code that creates autoreleased objects.
}
```

I would try something like the following (It shouldn't even need no extra autorelease pool)

```
+ (void)animateImagesWithPaths:(NSArray *)imagePaths onImageView:(UIImageView *)imageView duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    int count = (int)imagePaths.count;
    if(count <= 0) {
        // No images, no nothing
        return;
    }

    // We need to add the first image instantly
    imageView.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imagePaths[0]];

    if(count == 1) {
        // Nothing not animate with only 1 image. We are all done
        return;
    }

    NSTimeInterval interval = duration/(NSTimeInterval)(count-1);
    __block int imageIndex = 1; // We need to start with one as first is already consumed

    [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:interval repeats:true block:^(NSTimer * _Nonnull timer) {
        if(imageIndex < count) {
            imageView.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imagePaths[imageIndex]];
            imageIndex++;
        }
        else {
            // Animation ended. Invalidate timer.
            [timer invalidate];
        }
    }];

}
```

Comment: Thanks, yes I just came out with the similar solution and the key point is implement contentOfFile:.

Comment: @Boris Yes well if you used `imageNamed:` you should watch out as those images are being cached. And unfortunately you have no way to explicitly clear that cache. So yes, `contentOfFile` can sometimes be a better solution. Or rather always when you deal with images a lot.